# How to make that effect in After Effects?

Tags: adobe

How to make blurry, washed out effect like in this video the more far object location is the more blurry that object is.  And then object is moving bluriness also moving. How to do that?  Timestamp 32:48- 33:20

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is called "depth of field" and is the way cameras work, no effect.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that effect?

Comment: You need a DSLR or DSLM with a lens with a wide open aperture (f2.8 or below) open the aperture up as wide as you can.

Comment: What programm do i need to do that?

Comment: The effect is created in-camera, as a result of the physics of the lens and optical system, not in software.